# I'm using Facebook PHP-sdk v3.1.1 ... Do I still need to set cookie to "true"?

Tags: facebook

I just upgraded my php-sdk to the latest version (v3.1.1) .. Do I still need to set cookie to true like I used to do when using php-sdk v2.0 ? or should I just remove this line?

```
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'MyappId',
  'secret' => 'Mysecret',
  'cookie' => true
  ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO**, not anymore. Have you checked the Library ([`base_facebook.php`](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L205))?

```
/**
* Initialize a Facebook Application.
*
* The configuration:
* - appId: the application ID
* - secret: the application secret
* - fileUpload: (optional) boolean indicating if file uploads are enabled
*
* @param array $config The application configuration
*/
  public function __construct($config) {
    $this->setAppId($config['appId']);
    $this->setApiSecret($config['secret']);
    if (isset($config['fileUpload'])) {
      $this->setFileUploadSupport($config['fileUpload']);
    }

    $state = $this->getPersistentData('state');
    if (!empty($state)) {
      $this->state = $this->getPersistentData('state');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome!! thank you so much for the help. Also thanks for the tip on fileUpload. I was still using the old way.